# Why my Thread does not stop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-abort

I have the following code, where I start a `Thread` using a `ParameterizedThreadStart` object as constructor argument:

```
static object obj = new object();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ParameterizedThreadStart start = (o) =>
    {
        ThreadTest(o);
    };

    var t = new Thread(() => start(obj));
    t.Name = "t";
    t.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    obj = null;

    // Why the Thread (t) continue here??
    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static void ThreadTest(object o)
{
    while (o != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

After I set `obj` to `null` in the `ThreadTest` method the argument `o` is still a valid object, why?
How can I set the argument `o` to `null` using `obj`?

[I would prefer not to use Thread.Abort](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/08/22/thead-abort-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in C#, references are passed by value.

So, changing obj to refer to NULL in Main will not change the object to which o refers in ThreadTest.

Instead, you should keep both methods referring to the same object, and just change a property of the object to signal that the thread should exit.

Comment: Best answer.  Those relying on statics/globals are just bad - insufficiently flexible.

Answer (score 5):

`o` is a local parameter in your `ThreadTest` method.
Assigning the `obj` field does not affect that parameter.

You can fix this by getting rid of all of the parameters and using the field directly.  Once you do that, your code will still be broken, because the field is not volatile.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `obj` is *copied* when the method is called, rather than *referenced*.

Comment: @Servy: The object is not copied; the reference is.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and that's what `obj` is, a reference.  The reference is copied by value, so mutating the object that is reference would be "visible" in both places, but modifying `obj` (by assigning a new value to it) isn't "seen" because `obj` is copied *by value* to the method parameter.  The value that is copied simply happens to be a reference.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the value of a reference when calling the method. This means that any changes to the reference inside will not be seen outside and vice-versa. You'll probably want to synchronize directly at the global variable level:

```
static volatile object obj = new object();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadStart start = () =>
    {
        ThreadTest();
    };

    var t = new Thread(() => start());
    t.Name = "t";
    t.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    obj = null;

    // Why the Thread (t) continue here??
    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static void ThreadTest()
{
    while (obj != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Note also the `volatile` on the object. This will ensure that changes by one thread will be visible to other threads reading the value.

Comment: hey great answer, I ran into this same problem a few weeks ago and couldn't figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: Not so great - static/global not very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Boolean to control the thread stop like so:

```
static volatile bool runThread = true;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new Thread(ThreadTest);
    t.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    runThread = false;

    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static void ThreadTest()
{
    while (runThread)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: NP, it's easy to miss sometimes :-)